# Use $not in mongo db aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

New to mongo db aggregation:

Tried `$and` `$or` in mongodb aggregation, But could'nt figure out how to use `$not`

tried  `$and` `$or`  like this :

```
{$match: {
    $or: [
        {_id:ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a")},
        {_id:ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a")},
    ]
}}
```

it worked , but if i try the same thing with `$not` , it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running `$or` you can run [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html):

```
{
    $match: {
        _id: {
           $in: [
              ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a"),
              ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a")
           ]
        }
    }
}
```

For the opposite way you can try [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/index.html):

```
{
    $match: {
        _id: {
           $nin: [
              ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a"),
              ObjectId("5ab9cbe531c2ab715d42129a")
           ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SOyT4iJNR1x)

Comment: Also check out the examples at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/not/index.html#not-aggregation